# Website skipping when new element is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a fixed header at my page which apears when user scroll down the page (170 pixels down when page width is less then 992 pixels and 320 pixels down when page is greater then 992 pixels width).

In the moment when header apears there is a "jump" / "skips" of the whole page on the height of this header so it's looks bad - content goes rapiddly down.
How to remove this jump and display smoothly fixed header?

This is a code :

```
   function responsivecolumn(){

     if ($(document).width() <= 991)
     {
       $('.container #columns_inner #left-column').appendTo('.container #columns_inner');
       // ---------------- Fixed header responsive ----------------------
       $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
         if ($(window).scrollTop() > 170) {
           $('.header-top').addClass('fixed');
         } else {
           $('.header-top').removeClass('fixed');
         }
       });
     }
     else if($(document).width() >= 992)
     {
       $('.container #columns_inner #left-column').prependTo('.container #columns_inner');
       $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
         if ($(window).scrollTop() > 320) {
           $('.header-top').addClass('fixed');
         } else {
           $('.header-top').removeClass('fixed');
         }
       });
     }
   }
   $(document).ready(function(){responsivecolumn();});
   $(window).resize(function(){responsivecolumn();});
```

```
#header .header-top.fixed {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0px;
   background: #FFF;
   padding: 3px 0px;
   z-index: 9999;
   left: 0px;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
   -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
   transition: all 0.3s ease;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
   box-shadow: 0 0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
```

```
#header .header-top {
   padding-bottom: 0px;
   min-height: 48px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help. Solution is simple:

```
function responsivecolumn(){

  if ($(document).width() <= 991)
  {
    $('.container #columns_inner #left-column').appendTo('.container #columns_inner');
    // ---------------- Fixed header responsive ----------------------
    $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > 170) {
        $('.header-top').addClass('fixed');
        $('#header').css('padding-top', '48px');
      } else {
        $('.header-top').removeClass('fixed');
        $('#header').css('padding-top', '0px');
      }
    });
  }
  else if($(document).width() >= 992)
  {
    $('.container #columns_inner #left-column').prependTo('.container #columns_inner');
    $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > 320) {
        $('.header-top').addClass('fixed');
        $('#header').css('padding-top', '48px');
      } else {
        $('.header-top').removeClass('fixed');
         $('#header').css('padding-top', '0px');
      }
    });
  }
}
$(document).ready(function(){responsivecolumn();});
$(window).resize(function(){responsivecolumn();});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that `.header-top` is *in* the flow of the page (meaning it takes up space) when the page is first loaded. However, as the page is scrolled and `.fixed` is added, `.header-top` is taken *out* of the flow. Then the rest of the page jumps up to take up the spot where `.header-top` used to be. I'd need to see the HTML to be sure though.

Comment: You are right problem is that when the header change to fixed the old header disapear and the page goes up ... How to resolve it ?